# upgrade to 14.04 interrupted, back to 13, dash broken

Tags: upgrade, unity-dash

need to get the dash back and running so I can upgrade to 14.04 What to do?
Can't get to root, synaptic nor software updater.

Comment: Try `Ctrl+Alt+F2`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're on 13.10 you can press <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> and run it from command line.

```
sudo apt-get install update-manager-core (this may already be there)
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

After you manage to open a command line as per Musher instruction, you can try the following commands to fix your broken upgrade to 14.04

In a command line run:

```
lsb_release -a
```

That will let you know what version you have installed.
If in doubt, you can always fix an incomplete upgrade with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If while that is running you get errors, then you can run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

then repeat

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

That should fix any broken version 13 packages that did not upgrade properly to 14.04